# Only first EditText is being updated

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-edittext

I am trying to update an `EditText(for Unit Price)` on the basis of selected item in the `Spinner`.

[image: Dynamic Addition of data]

As you can see in the image above, every `plus Button` adds a `Layout(Spinner, Button and two EditText)`.

So when the first `Layout` is added, the `EditText(for "Unit Price")` displays the value for selected product in spinner but when I add more layout, the `Unit Price` is not updated in new `EditText` and also when I change the selected item of any `Spinner` the value of very first `EditText` is updated.

This is my code:-

```
  final Spinner s = (Spinner) newView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        try {
            loadSpinnerData(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO: catch exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String selecteditem = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                try {
                    loadUnitPrice(selecteditem);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

 private void loadUnitPrice(String selectedItem) throws IOException {

        // database handler
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        String price = db.getUnitPrice(selectedItem);
        System.out.println(price);
        EditText unitprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPrice);
        unitprice.setText(price);

    }
```

Comment: Can you plz provide us with the code snippet that is doing this?

Comment: @MagicMicky I have added the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally solved the problem by using this:-*

```
            s = (Spinner) newView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
            //newView was missing earlier in the line below      
            unitprice = (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.editPrice);  

            try {
                loadSpinnerData(s);
                s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {

                        String selecteditem = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        try {
                            loadUnitPrice(selecteditem, unitprice);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //TODO: catch exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**`loadUnitPrice()`:-**

```
private void loadUnitPrice(String selectedItem, EditText unitprice) throws IOException {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

        String price = db.getUnitPrice(selectedItem);
        System.out.println(price);

        unitprice.setText(price);   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem I think is that you have duplicate ids in your code for your EditText(s).  Can you check if you have a unique id per EditText

Comment: but there is no problem when I populate my dynamically generated spinners with almost same code :(

Comment: try using tags and findViewWithTag

Comment: This should be comment!! Can't accept as a answer.!!